# ++someVariable vs. someVariable++ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, increment, post-increment, pre-increment, unary-operator

In JavaScript you can use `++` operator before (*pre-increment*) or after the variable name (*post-increment*).  What, if any, are the differences between these ways of incrementing a variable?

Comment: See also the language-agnostic [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/484462/1048572)

Comment: I was thinking about this yesterday reading [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458154/393280) to the question about [bad assumptions in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3457967/393280).  In all cases, can we guarantee that Javascript behaves this way?  Or do you think it's bad practice to use the increment statement within a more complex statement at all?

Comment: [The previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469885/393280#comment103574142_3469885) is actually a copy of [an answer (a non-answer, rather) I posted in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469966/393280). I have deleted the answer, but [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [had replied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469966/393280#comment3620204_3469966) with: "Looking at ECMA-262, it seems reasonably well-specified."

Comment: @palswim It's better to use them as standalone statements, and not within a more complex statement. Keeping it by itself improves readability and reduces confusion

Comment: This SO page makes things extremely unnecessarily complicated. `i++` returns the value of `i` and increment it by one, `++i` increment `i` by one and returns the incremented value. If `i` has `5`, `i++` will return `5` but then i will have `6`, and `++i` will return 6 and `i` will have 6.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Same as in other languages:

- `++x` (pre-increment) means "increment the variable; the value of the expression is the final value"
- `x++` (post-increment) means "remember the original value, then increment the variable; the value of the expression is the original value"

Now when used as a standalone statement, they mean the same thing:

```
x++;
++x;
```

The difference comes when you use the value of the expression elsewhere. For example:

```
x = 0;
y = array[x++]; // This will get array[0]

x = 0;
y = array[++x]; // This will get array[1]
```

Comment: Curses, I nearly beat you to an answer had I not stopped to load up a practical jsfiddle answer. ;-)

Comment: What would this look like if you used `+ 1` instead of `++`? Is there a way to increment before or after when adding numbers?

Comment: I would like to know why if you do this operation const r1 =(x++)+(x++); it does not produce the expected result according to your example.

Comment: @JeanJimenez: Well it produces the result *I* expect. For example, if `x` starts off as 10, the value of `r1` is 21, which is 10+11. The value of the first `x++` expression is 10 and `x` is incremented to 11. The value of the second `x++` expression is 11 and `x` is incremented to 12.

Comment: Dear @JonSkeet thanks for that super-fast response, I’m new to learning JavaScript and my confusion is regarding why one increments and the another doesn't.

Comment: @JeanJimenez: They both increment `x` (which is why `x` ends up as 12 afterwards if it starts off as 10), and in both cases the value of the expression is the value of `x` *before* that increment. (But the second `x++` is evaluated *after* the first increment takes place, of course...)

Comment: I um, have been working with JS for many years, and I uh... never knew ++variable was a thing. I cannot think of a single time I've seen it used until I read an article on functional programming and saw it in a loop comparison example. So great question :D

Comment:  Additional info for i++ vs. ++i in loops @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885719/i-vs-i-in-a-javascript-for-loop

Comment: I highly recommend to only use this syntax as a standalone statement. If you use it inside other expressions it just causes confusion and makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 83):

- `++x` increments the value, then evaluates and stores it.
- `x++` evaluates the value, then increments and stores it.

```js
var n = 0, m = 0;

alert(n++); /* Shows 0, then stores n = 1 */
alert(++m); /* Shows 1, then stores m = 1 */
```

Note that there are slight performance benefits to using `++x` where possible, because you read the variable, modify it, then evaluate and store it. Versus the `x++` operator where you read the value, evaluate it, modify it, then store it.

Answer (score 12):

As I understand them if you use them standalone they do the same thing. If you try to output the result of them as an expression then they may differ. Try alert(i++) as compared to alert(++i) to see the difference. i++ evaluates to i before the addition and ++i does the addition before evaluating.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xaDC4/ for an example.

Answer (score 12):

I've an explanation of understanding post-increment and pre-increment. So I'm putting it here.

Lets assign `0` to `x`

```
let x = 0;
```

Lets start with post-increment

```
console.log(x++); // Outputs 0
```

Why?

Lets break the `x++` expression down

```
x = x;
x = x + 1;
```

First statement returns the value of `x` which is `0`

And later when you use `x` variable anywhere, then the second statement is executed

Second statement returns the value of this `x + 1` expression which is `(0 + 1) = 1`

Keep in mind the value of `x` at this state which is `1`

Now lets start with pre-increment

```
console.log(++x); // Outputs 2
```

Why?

Lets break the `++x` expression down

```
x = x + 1;
x = x;
```

First statement returns the value of this `x + 1` expression which is `(1 + 1) = 2`

Second statement returns the value of `x` which is `2` so `x = 2` thus it returns `2`

Hope this would help you understand what post-increment and pre-increment are!

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = 1;
var b = ++a;
alert('a:' + a + ';b:' + b); //a:2;b:2

var c = 1;
var d = c++;
alert('c:' + c + ';d:' + d); //c:2;d:1
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9ycops9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = 0, y = 0;

//post-increment: i++ returns value then adds one to it
console.log('x++ will log: ', x++); //0
console.log('x after x++ : ', x);    //1

//pre-increment: adds one to the value, then returns it
console.log('++y will log: ', ++y); //1
console.log('y after ++y : ', y);   //1
```

Answer (score -1):

It is clearer and faster to use `++i` if possible :

- `++i` guarantees that you are using a value of `i` that will remains the same unless you change `i`
- `i++` allows to use a value of `i` which will change in the "near future", it is not desirable if possible

Of course, it's not really much faster, only a little.