# JavaScript increments

Tags: javascript, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

I know you can add one to a variable simply by doing `i++` (assuming i is your variable).  This can best be seen when iterating through an array or using it in a "for" statement.  After finding some code to use online, I noticed that the for statement used `++i` (as apposed to `i++`).

I was wondering if there was any significant difference or if the two are even handled any differently.

Comment: Answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes there is a **big** difference.

```
var i = 0;

var c = i++; //c = 0, i = 1
    c = ++i; //c = 2, i = 2
    //to make things more confusing:
    c = ++c + c++; //c = 6
    //but:
    c = c++ + c++; //c = 13
```

And here is a fiddle to put it all together: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ZcKSF/

Comment: +1 because you show the behavior instead of just describing it as "pre-increment/post-increment".

Comment: This will be the answer... in 8 minutes :3

Answer (score 4):

The value of `++i` is `i + 1` and the value of `i++` is just `i`. After either has evaluated, `i` is `i + 1`. It's a difference in timing, which is why they're often called 'pre-increment' and 'post-increment'. In a for loop, it rarely matters, though.

Answer (score 3):

People like Douglas Crockford advise not to use that way of incrementing, amongst other reasons because of what Rafe Kettler described. No matter how experienced you are, sometimes  `++i/i++` *will* suprise you. The alternative is to simply add 1 to i using `i += 1`, readable, understandable and unambiguous.

Comment: Nice post :)  Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this link : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp 
it's post increment versus pre increment. They both end up incrementing the value but one returns the value BEFORE incrementing (++y) and the other one returns the value AFTER (y++). 
However, it doesn't make any difference when using it in a for loop --

```
for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) { ... }
```

is the same as

```
for( var i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) { ... }
```

Comment: [Please let's not link to w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 2):

```
a=1;
b=1;
c=++a;//the value of a is incremented first and then assigned to c
d=b++;//the value of b is assigned to d first then incremented
```

now if you print a,b,c,d..the output will be:

2 2 2 1

Answer (score 1):

++i is called pre-increment and i++ is called post-increment. The difference is when the variable is incremented. Pre-incrementing a variable usually adds 1 and then uses that value, while post-incrementation uses the variable and then increments.