# What's the difference between ++i and i++ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

on my quest to learn and improve my JavaScript I came across a script that has a switch / case statement and I noticed some variables are incremented using ++ with the variable before the ++ and then some variables have the ++ after the variable. What's the difference between these? Here's an example of what I'm trying to explain notice the m and y variables.

```
 switch(f){
        case 0:{

            ++m;
            if(m==12){
                m=0;
                y++;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1:{

            --m;
            if(m==-1){
                m=11;
                y--;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:{

            ++y;
            break;
        }
        case 3:{

            --y;
            break;
        }
        case 4:{

            break;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [++someVariable vs. someVariable++ in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`++i` returns the value of `i` after it has been incremented.  `i++` returns the value of `i` before incrementing.

When the `++` comes before its operand it is called the "pre-increment" operator, and when it comes after it is called the "post-increment" operator.

This distinction is only important if you do something with the result.

```
var i = 0, j = 0;

alert(++i);  // alerts 1
alert(j++);  // alerts 0
```

One thing to note though is that even though `i++` returns the value before incrementing, it still returns the value after it has been converted to a number.

So

```
var s = "1";
alert(typeof s++);  // alerts "number"
alert(s);  // alerts 2, not "11" as if by ("1" + 1)
```

Comment: And they are called pre-increment and post-increment operators.

Comment: Does pre-incrementing or post-incrementing in the for loop have any effect on the loop? These two cases: 
`for (i=0; i<5; i++)` vs `for (i=0; i<5; ++i)`

Comment: @Mihailo, no difference.  I tend to pre-increment out of a habit learned writing C++; it used to be the case that pre-incrementing was a bit more efficient for some iterator types.  AFAICT, there's no difference for JS.

Answer (score 13):

The same difference as any other c-style `++` incrementor.

`foo = ++i` is the same as:

```
i = i + 1;
foo = i;
```

`foo = i++` is the same as;

```
foo = i;
i = i + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var i = 0;
alert('i is ' + (++i)); // i is 1

// i is now 1

var i = 0;
alert('i is ' + (i++)); // i is 0

// i is now 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS (as well as C, Perl, and probably a dozen other languages), the ++i operator increments i *before* it evaluates the statement, and i++ increments it after. Same with --.

Example:

```
var i=1;
alert(i++);
```

Will show "1", but:

```
var i=1;
alert(++i);
```

Will show "2".

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate, assuming:

```
var a = 1;
```

then

```
var b = ++a;
```

results in

```
true === (b === 2 && a === 2)
```

while

```
var b = a++;
```

results in

```
true === (b === 1 && a === 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

++i is pre-increment, i++ is post-increment.

If you're only incrementing the variable and not using the result at the same time they are equivalent.

In which case you really should use i += 1 for readability (says Douglas Crockford..)