# For each div load image loads image number twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, foreach

I'm dynamically loading images in a grid, which displays images with a link to some lightbox. This is the way im currently doing it:

```
$(".selection_thumb").each( function(i) {
    $(this).append("<a data-lightbox='image-1' href='img/folder/folder/"+(++i)+".jpg'><img src='img/folder/"+(++i)+".jpg' alt='alttext' /></a>");  
});
```

But it seems to be loading this:

```
<a data-lightbox="image-1" href="img/folder/folder/1.jpg"><img src="img/folder/2.jpg" alt="alttext" /></a>
```

But it needs to be:

```
<a data-lightbox="image-1" href="img/folder/folder/1.jpg"><img src="img/folder/1.jpg" alt="alttext" /></a>
```

So it is loading different numbers 1 and 2 instead of 1 and 1.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
var cache = null;

$(".selection_thumb").each( function(i) {
    cache = ++i; 
    $(this).append("<a data-lightbox='image-1' href='img/folder/folder/"+ cache +".jpg'><img src='img/folder/"+ cache  +".jpg' alt='alttext' /></a>");  
});
```

Comment: Thanks that also worked, neither can i verify your answer but will do so in a few min

Comment: @user2099810 Glad to help.! you can accept any one of the answer as per your wish.! :)

Comment: I meant accepting your answer by clicking the V it has a 14min wait or so hehe

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `i++` not `++i` because ++i adds diferently

> ++i returns the value of i after it has been incremented. i++ returns the value of i before incrementing.

Quoted from [What's the difference between ++i and i++ in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378670/1696560)

Comment: Thanks, that worked can't verify your answer yet ( but will do so in a few min )