# javascript function return clarification required

Tags: javascript, function

In this function, am expecting the return value to be increment of variable value . However , i am getting original value ,

here is my function:

```
var num = function(){
    var a = 0;
    return a++;
}

alert(num()); //it giving the result as 0 instead of 1...why?
```

can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: I agree, but as a first time i should get the value. look the great answers..

Answer (score 4):

The ++ acts after the 'return':

`return a++`  ==> return `a`, then add 1 to `a`

`return ++a` ==> add 1 to `a`, then return

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript).

Comment: `return` actually acts last with both. `a++` just gives the *old* value of `0` to `return`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var num = function(){
    var a = 0;
    return ++a;
}
```

++a give the value after operation a++ give the value then do the operation