# strange behavior with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, logic, expression, operator-keyword, ternary

I tried to program a function, that converts javascript objects to a http-compatible string. I achieved what I intendet to do, but I don't know why it works.
My final function is:

```
function paramify (p) {
    var n = 0, r = "";
    for (var i in p) {
        r+=(n++==0?"":"&")+i+"="+p[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

The version without the ternary operator is:

```
function paramify (p) {
    var n=0, r="";
    for(var i in p){
        if(n++!=0){
            r+="&"
        }
        r+=i+"="+p[i]
    }
    return r;
}
```

Example json-object:

```
{"authToken":"aqsd2","username":"test","password":"1234"}
```

will become:

```
authToken=aqsd2&username=test&password=1234
```

(as intendet)

May somebody explain me, why this works? I didn't expect n++ to become 0 when n is already 0.

Comment: Your'e using post increment, the value of `n` will be used in the comparison, and after that the increment is done.

Comment: Always put spaces for readability e.g. your expression should be written as `r += (n++ == 0? "": "&") + i + "=" +p[i];`

Comment: Just to clarify, the version with the ternary is equivalent to the if version. Are you getting different outputs?

Comment: No, I just added the non-ternary version, because I thought some people might not know that operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference between pre and post increment. It's explained in this question: [++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

"variable++" is incremented after being evaluated, "++variable" is incremented before being evaluated.  Same goes for the "--" operator.

reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/26k41698(v=vs.94).aspx