# Copying object properties into an array using for/in

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

`I'm reading 'JavaScript: the definitive guide' and I'm getting hung up on an example:

“you can use code like the following to copy the names of all object properties into an array"

```
var o = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
var a = [], i = 0;
for(a[i++] in o) /* empty */;
```

"following the code above with this line enumerates the array indexes 0, 1, and 2"

```
for(i in a) console.log(i);
```

Can someone please explain to me like I'm five how the first `for/in` loop works? It seems to me `a[i++]` would evaluate to `1` on the first time through the loop, not `0`.

Comment: `i++` actually evaluates to `i` (in this case, 0): when `++` follows the variable, the latter is incremented *after* evaluation.

Comment: `i++` only sets `i` to `i+1` after the expression evaluates, so it's still `0` until the loop runs once. It has nothing to do with being a `for... in` specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please explain to me like I'm five how the first for/in loop works?

A [for-in loop](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4) does allow any left-hand-side expression (that is, something you could possibly assign to) before the `in`, not only plain variables. So

```
for(a[i++] in {x:1, y:2, z:3})
```

is just the same as

```
a[i++] = "x";
a[i++] = "y";
a[i++] = "z";
```

> It seems to me `a[i++]` would evaluate to 1 on the first time through the loop, not 0.

`i++` is a postfix expression, so no - it will yield the value `0` (that `i` had before) and then increment it. See [++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused by the time at which your variable `i` is incremented.
You could expect `i` to evaluate to `1` only if you do `for(a[++i] in o) /* empty */;`

It's called post/pre increment. Post will increment after your instruction, and pre will increment before.