# The Difference between ++num vs num++

Tags: javascript

After reading these two posts:

- [++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)
- http://community.sitepoint.com/t/variable-vs-variable/6371

I am still confused on the following code:

```
var num = 0;

num++ // returns 0

++num // returns 1
```

Why dose `num++` return 0?

I understand that it assigns first, then adds one, ***but I still don't understand why it doesn't display the 1.***

```
var num = 0;

num++ // returns 0

num // returns 1
```

I am really confused with the following example:

**Example:**

```
var num = 0;

num++
// assigns then increments

// So if it assigns the num = 0, then increments to 1, Where is one being 
//stored? Is it assigned anywhere?
```

Or does it assign the expression.

(I imagine the expression is this: num = num + 1;)

This is probably my best guess but it still isn't 100% clear to me, I still don't understand why num++ displays/returns 0 instead of having the expression being evaluated and returning 1.

Comment: `num++ Why dose num++ return 0?` Because it first returns and *then* applies `+1` operation. `++num` first adds `+1` and *then* returns incremented value.

Comment: `num++` => `return num`, then `num += 1`.

Comment: you should read a basic java book... jesus!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe looking at the specification helps.

### [Postfix increment operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3.1) (`num++`)

> The production *PostfixExpression : LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] ++* is evaluated as follows:
>
> **1.** Let *lhs* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.

That simply means we are looking at what's before the `++`, e.g. `num` in `num++`.

> **2.** Throw a `SyntaxError` exception if the following conditions are all true: [left out for brevity]

This step makes sure that `lhs` really refers to a variable. The postfix operator only works on variables, using e.g. a literal, `1++`, would be a syntax error.

> **3.** Let *oldValue* be [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)([GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*lhs*)).

Get the value of the variable represented by *lhs* and store it in `oldValue`. Imagine it to be something like `var oldValue = num;`. If `num = 0` then `oldValue = 0` as well.

> **4.** Let *newValue* be the result of adding the value 1 to *oldValue*, using the same rules as for the + operator (see [11.6.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.3)).

Simply add 1 to `oldValue` and store the result in `newValue`. Something like `newValue = oldValue + 1`. In our case `newValue` would be `1`.

> **5.** Call [PutValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2)(*lhs*, *newValue*).

This assigns the new value to *lhs* again. The equivalent is `num = newValue;`. So `num` is `1` now.

> **6.** Return *oldValue*.

Return the value of `oldValue` which is still `0`.

So again, in pseudo JavaScript code, `num++` is equivalent to:

```
var oldValue = num;           // remember current value
var newValue = oldValue + 1;  // add one to current value
num = newValue;               // sore new value
return oldValue;              // return old value
```

---

### [Prefix increment operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4) (++num)

The algorithm is exactly the same as for the postfix operator, with one difference: In the last step, `newValue` is returned instead of `oldValue`:

> 6. Return *newValue*.

Answer (score 3):

Take the following example:

```
var num = 0;
var result = 0;
```

The following:

```
result = num++;
```

Is equal to saying:

```
result = num;
num = num + 1;
```

On the other hand, this:

```
result = ++num;
```

Is more equitable with this:

```
num = num + 1;
result = num;
```

The two statements are kinda like shorthand for doing common operations.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `num++` as a statement, JavaScript will evaluate `num` first -- which is why it's showing the zero -- then increment. That's why it's called the *post*-increment operator.

If you were to do this, you'll see what's happening more clearly:

```
var num = 0;
num++;        // Outputs 0 (current value, set in previous step), then increments
num;          // Outputs 1 (current value, incremented in previous step)
```

With the *pre*-increment, the incrementation happens first, so you'd get:

```
var num = 0;
++num;        // Outputs 1
num;          // Outputs 1
```