# i++ vs. ++i in a JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

Because of JSLint, I almost always use `i += 1` to increment a JavaScript for loop, but for quick and dirty scripts, I use `i++` instead.
However, I see a lot of for loops in other people's code in which they increment `i` by doing `++i` instead.

As far as I know, there is no difference in meaning between `i++` and `++i`, and jsPref shows no difference in performance.
As such, I'm wondering where the convention of doing `++i` comes from and why people tend to do it.

Does anyone know why a lot of JS coders tend to prefer `++i` over `i++` when incrementing the counter in a for loop?
Thanks.

Comment: It completely dosent matter, incrementing part executes after block of code and then condition is reevaluated. So regardless of what's returned by i++ or ++i has no effect.. however i used to know what drove everyone to use ++i .. it was some performance tip from some other language.

Comment: Basically idea was that i++ is less efficent because it caused a copy to be created in memory. One that is returned and original one that is increased. Whereas, ++i meant just increase the original one then return it...however with smarter compilers this is a non issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JS and PHP it does not make any difference, I think even in Java it does not make any difference but in pure c when compiler is not optimizing code it does, and that is why a lot of people use ++i because they are used to it from c.

EDIT:
This is an answer for JS if you want history of pre and post increment searc C/C++ pre/post increment. Or see comments on @Orvev's answer.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, and you stated it the first time without me having to comment. As such, I will mark this answer as correct as soon as I am able to.

Comment: @HartleySan Strange reason for marking the less complete answer as correct.

Answer (score 13):

The difference is that `i++` returns the value of `i` before incrementing and `++i` the value of `i` after incrementing. There is no difference if you ignore the return value, e.g. in:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

}
```

The habit of using `++i` over `i++` comes from C, where people were worried that storing the old value for `i` in `i++` would incur a performance penalty.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between pre- and post-incrementation. That was not the question. I'm more asking where the `++i` convention comes from.

Comment: @HartleySan Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Way back in the day (we're talking IE6/7 here!), I recall benchmarking both forms and found that there was a small performance improvement with `++i` instead of `i++`. My (unproven) theory was that a non-optimizing JS engine had to do a tiny bit more work in the `i++` case: it had to save the previous value in case it would be used - and being a non-optimizing engine it didn't realize that the value would in fact *not* be used and didn't need to be saved.

However, with modern browsers there is no significant difference. If anything, `i++` seems to be a tiny bit faster in many browsers.

Here are some tests of a variety of different loops:

http://jsperf.com/mikes-loops/5

Look for the results for "Traditional Loop" (this uses `++i`) and "Traditional Loop with i++".

Regarding JSLint's requirement that one should *never* use `++i` or `i++` but only use `i += 1` instead, that is simply insane and over-controlling, like so many other things in JSLint.

Personally I recommend [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) instead. It is less dogmatic, much more practical, and easier to customize to your own style.

Comment: This is indeed a great one :) I did not know this one.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a difference, however not when used in a for loop.

In an expression, `i++` evaluates to the previous value of `i`, and then `i` is incremented. `++i` increments first, and evaluates then.

For this reason, some programmers prefer to write `++i` in their for-loops — either because they're used to it, or because they feel it is "more right" somehow.

**edit:** More probable is the solution Overv proposed: a relict from C.

Comment: OP obviously knows that, given that he tagged the post with `post-increment` and `pre-increment`. :)

Comment: Yes, I know the different between pre- and post-incrementing a variable, but I was specifically asking about a for loop. Also, I know that there is no difference, I simply want to know why people tend to do `++i`. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think it's just because they're used to it because they usually pre-increment, or because they feel it is "more right". Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No need to delete your answer. I'm more just wondering if there are certain other languages in which `++i` is more common, thus programmers coming from those languages to JS prefer that notation or something. Just curious, more than anything.