# Counter small issue (does not work smoothly)

Tags: javascript, counter

In this jsfiddle below you will notice that the incrementing or the decrementing(?) does not work perfectly well - It goes one number off (up or down) - I am looking for a way to make it perfect.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sergelie/8d3th1cb/3/

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <input id="button" type="button" value="+" /> 
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="-" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

The idea is to go from 0 up to unlimited, and down to stop at 0 (not to -1 the way it does right now).

```
var count = 1;
$("#button").on('click', function () {
$(this).val(count++).button("refresh");
});
$("#button2").on('click', function () {
if (count>-1)
$("#button").val(count--).button("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `++count` and `--count` instead so that the values are incremented/decremented before and the value of the expression is the final value:

```
var count = 1;
$("#button").on('click', function() {
    $(this).val(++count).button("refresh");
});
$("#button2").on('click', function() {
    if (count > 0) $("#button").val(--count).button("refresh");
});
```

See also: [++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript])

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prefix operator (++count/--count) instead (initializing count to 0):

```
var count = 0;
$("#button").on('click', function() {
  $(this).val(++count).button("refresh");
});
$("#button2").on('click', function() {
  if (count > 0)
    $("#button").val(--count).button("refresh");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8d3th1cb/5/)**

Comment: your `if (count > -1)` line needs to be updated to `if (count > 0)`.

Comment: Perfect thanks! (and I changed to "if (count > -0)" - so it does not go in the negative - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$("#button").on('click', function () {
    $(this).val(++count).button("refresh");
});
$("#button2").on('click', function () {
    if (count>0)
        $("#button").val(--count).button("refresh");
});
```

Read about the position of increment and decrement operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).