# What does ++ mean in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I've seen various people use stuff like `i++`, and I know that is also used in a for-loop.

But what exactly does `++` do to a variable? I cannot seem to find any documentation on what it does.

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate of [++someVariable vs. someVariable++ in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469885/1048572) according to the canonical reference it is currently marked as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to increment.

```
var i = 1;
i++; // i becomes 2.
```

Answer (score 4):

The ++ notation is the increment operators.

i++ 
is the same thing of

i = i +1

here you can see the completly list of this operators:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp