# javascript: difference in return value between operators -- and -=

Tags: javascript

Given the following code:

```
var x = 0;

function decrement(num) {
  return num--;
}

var y = decrement(x);
console.log(y);    // 0
```

Versus the following:

```
var x = 0;

function decrement(num) {
  return num -= 1;    // this is the only difference between the functions
}

var y = decrement(x);
console.log(y);    // 0
```

Why does `y--` return `0` from the function while `y -= 1` returns `-1`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you didn't also run `--y`; but you'll probably find the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks. did not realize that you could not easily search for single characters on SO.  Would explain why I could not find an answer to this question at first.

Comment: Rather than using Stackoverflow as a reference, trying using an actual reference as a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This is a duplicate question, answered here: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

I couldn't find an answer to this question on SO, and managed to answer my question while researching it and composing the question.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)

The code example is using the postfix incrementing operator. A postfix operator will first return the current value and then increment it.

```
var x = 1;
x++;   // returns 1, x === 2
```

This is in contrast to the prefix incrementing operator, which will first increment the value and then return the incremented value.

```
var y = 1;
--y    // returns 0, y === 0
```

Regarding the `+=` and `-=` assignment operators: these operators also increment the value and then return the incremented value.

Comment: Check out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Remember prefix and postfix. When I do `return num--` I return the value of `num` only, detuction comes after I return the value.

In short , operator precendence