# i'm new to coding. i need a quick explanation

Tags: javascript, numbers

```
var x = 3;
var y = x++;
```

Can someone tell me why `var y = 3` and `x++ = 4`.

I assumed `x++ = 4` therefore `y = 4` but it's not.

This dummy needs help understanding why `y is not 4` but `3`

Comment: Java and JavaScript use the same syntax for variables increments. So Java explanation in that regard applies to JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `var y = x++;` means assign value of **x** to **y** and then increment the value of **x** by 1.

similarly `var y = ++x;` will have opposite meaning ie. **increment `x` first** and **then** assign it to `y`.

so.

```
x = 3
var y = x++; //means y = 3, x = 4;
```

and

```
x = 3
var y = ++x; //means y = 4, x = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

x++ => The ++ after the variable is the post-increment operator. It means that the variable uses the original value and then increments the value after an operation

```js
var x=3;
var y=x++;
console.log(y)
```

Similarly there is a pre-increment operator that increments values first and then uses that value

```js
var x=3;
var y=++x;
console.log(y)
```

Basically
++x: load x , increment, use.
x++: load x , use, increment.
This is the reason why x++ still gives 3. The values is first used then incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `++` is after `x` : [javascript increment and decrement](https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed)

> When you use the increment/decrement operator after the operand, the value will be returned before the operand is increased/decreased.

To in crement the value before returning it, put the `++` before the variable name `++x` :

```js
var x = 3;
var y = x++;

console.log(x,y)

var a = 3;
var b = ++a;

console.log(a,b);
```