# How can I use a state in a FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` and I want to show a number like `quantity` of `product`. So I use a `state` for that. Now when I press on `TouchableOpacity` to change quantity to 1 working fine in console, but I can't see any change in FlatList.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      quantity : 0,
    }
```

Increment quantity:

```
incrementCount=()=>{

    if(this.state.quantity != 10){
      console.log(this.state.quantity);
     this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        quantity: this.state.quantity + 1,
      }));
    }
}
```

FlatList:

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) =>

          <View>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>

            <Text>{this.state.quantity}</Text>                            
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.incrementCount} activeOpacity={0.5}>
               <AntDesign name="plus" size={15}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
      }
    />
```

Comment: there is no `this.state.dataSource` in your state, the data of the ListView is undefined

Comment: @Vencovsky Sorry.. I delete many codes... The problem is not about that. I think we cant change state when we use a state in listView.

Comment: Maybe this will change something `this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        quantity: prevState.quantity + 1,
      }))`

Comment: @Vencovsky Not working...

Answer (score 0):

Listview is deprecated now use Flatlist instead of this.

Refer this official doc for more information [react-native listview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview)

Comment: I use flatList now and in not working in flatList ,too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the common problem about *pre-increment* vs *post-increment* in javascript (you can read more about this here: [++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript) )

You can solve this problem by simply incrementing the variable before the setState:

```js
const quantity = this.state.quantity + 1;
this.setState({ quantity }) // this is ES6 syntax
```

Anyway, you should not use *ListView* because it's deprecated. ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html )
There are other components:

- FlatList ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist )
- SectionList ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist )
- VirtualizedList ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist )

Comment: no different..  My code working fine but not in listView.. I think I should use other components..

Comment: I use flatList now and in not working in flatList ,too.