# Can someone explain why the incrementing below is not adding a +1

Tags: javascript

Can someone help explain to me why is it that

```js
let one = 1;

function chg(arg) {
  return arg++ // --> shouldn't this be similar to arg + arg? but it's outputting 1
}

console.log(one);
console.log(chg(one));
```

Comment: If `one` is `1`. Then `one++` is `1` and `one` becomes `2`. What you're looking for is `++one`.

Comment: It works if you use `return ++args;`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript

Comment: primitive values are handed over as value, not as reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [++someVariable vs. someVariable++ in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Comment: The are two problems in this code. The first one with post-increment ist stated in the other answer.

But you have another problem with the datatype number. It's a primitive type and you are passing it to a function which in fact copies the value `one` to `arg`. `arg` is incremented after return but immediately forgotten. `one = chg(one)` would change your value in combination with `return ++arg`

Answer (score 5):

`x++` is the post-increment expression, i.e. its value is `x`, and after that value is returned, the variable is incremented by one.

`++x` is the pre-increment expression, i.e. `x` is first incremented by one, then returned.

You'll want `++x` here – or since this is a function argument, just be clearer and use `x + 1`; the `++` modification will have no effect anyway.

Comment: The last sentence is crucial, because I can already anticipate the "why doesn't `chg(one); chg(one);` keep increasing?" followup.

Comment: It's not the same thing tho, "one" +1 will return "one1", whereas "one"++ will return NaN

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. You need to use pre-increment instead of post-increment

```js
let one = 1;

function chg(arg) {
  return ++arg // --> shouldn't this be similar to arg + arg? but it's outputting 1
}

console.log(one);
console.log(chg(one));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edited your code:

```
let one = 1;

function chg(arg) {
  return ++arg; 
}

console.log(one);
console.log(chg(one));
```

or can also be like this

```
let one = 1;

function chg(arg) {
  return arg;
}

console.log(one);
console.log(chg(++one));
```

Comment: so it means, putting a ++ at the front returns the memory where i stored 1, and then it added a 1 in it's place?

Also, why would it be different it i put it in a function. If let's say I instead put as below, it increments properly.

`let one = 1;
one++

function chg(arg) {
  return ++arg // --> shouldn't this be similar to arg + arg? but it's outputting 1
}

console.log(one);
console.log(chg(one));`

Comment: Here the variable arg is not shifted by reference but only by value.

Comment: sorry tool me a while to edit that

Answer (score 0):

```
let one = 1;

function chg(arg) {
  return arg+1 // This is more readable code
}

console.log(one);
console.log(chg(one));
```