# What do I have to use '+(x)+', '+(y)+' in D3? instead of using d3.event.x&d3.event.y?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Always thank you guys for super kind and detailed guides.
I just came across a curiosity in d3 syntax.
I tried to move svg object imported from illustrator.
Once I call drag function and move according to my mouse position, 
it spits out related to x&y position.

This  question is not about meaning of += or ++.
So please do not mark this question as a similar one as quesitons asknig meaning of +=.

**However!**

When I do the code below,

```
<script>
    var drag = d3.drag().on('drag',moving)
    // var xloc=5
    // var yloc=5

    function moving(){
  let xloc = d3.event.x
  let yloc = d3.event.y
  d3.selectAll('.furn1')
     .attr('transform','translate('+(xloc-250)+','+(yloc-250)+')')
  }



  d3.selectAll('g').classed('dragable',true)
  .call(drag)


</script>
```

The error is gone, and it works perfectly.

What is

'+( )+'

in this code? and why just d3.event.x is not working?
I checked d3.event.x by adding it with d3.event.y.
And the console.log value was number which means d3.event.x is already number not string.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: when you are trying to use variables inside javascript/jQery text then you use `+<variable as well as operation if any>+`symbol along with single or double quotes. Also you can do `.attr('transform','translate('+(d3.event.x-250)+','+(d3.event.y-250)+')')` directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for a [`translate` transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Translate) in SVG is: `translate(x [,y])`, with x and y being numbers.

In the shared portion of code, `+` operator is used to [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) the coordinate values inside the string `translate()`.

`d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` could have been used directly, achieving the same effect:

```
.attr('transform','translate(' + ( d3.event.x -250 ) + ',' + ( d3.event.y - 250 ) + ')')
```