# Array.prototype.reduce() return output wrong in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function getCount(objects) {
    return objects.reduce((count, o) => {
        return count++;
    }, 0);
}
console.log(getCount([{x: 1, y: 1},{x: 2, y: 2}]));
```

Result: 0

But I want it to return 2.

Comment: `++count`, you need to increment *before* using the value.

Comment: Use `count + 1` instead. You're post incrementing, so the original value is returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [++someVariable vs. someVariable++ in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Comment: The `++` syntax is convenient, but can sometimes lead to confusing bugs if not used properly. The Go language has that syntax, but they don't let it return a result; it only mutates the variable. This was done to avoid exactly these kinds of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this

```
function getCount(objects) {
    return objects.reduce((count, o) => {
        return count+=1;
    }, 0);
}
```

or

```
function getCount(objects) {
    return objects.reduce((count, o) => {
        return count+1;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Well, it works, but `return count + 1` would be cleaner.