# increase object value on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to increase object value just like   loop i++ ,  but in object didnt worked ,
how to increase this value ? any methods?

```js
const object = {
price:30
}

console.log(object.price++);
```

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `++` like that is the post-increment operator meaning `object.price++` returns `object.price` first then increments. You want the pre-increment operator `++object.price`.

```js
const object = {
  price:30
}

console.log(++object.price);
```