# What is the differences between these two for loops?

Tags: javascript

Both of the consolt results are same. Anyone can explain me why it is being like that?

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd8mP.png)

```
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  console.log(index)
}
```

```
for (let index = 0; index < 5; ++index) {
  console.log(index)
}
```

Comment: Which difference did you expect?

Comment: Its work same, because index++ will increment after initialization and ++index will increment first then initialize, you are not initializing there you just incrementing.

Comment: The second result should be 1,2,3,4

Comment: @ozankurucu They should both be the same because both snippets start with `index = 0` before the first iteration.  Both snippets check `index < 5` before each iteration.   and both snippets increment `index` at the end of each iteration.    The only difference between the snippets is between pre- and post- increment, however this difference is irrelevant to the flow of a `for`-loop because this difference only affects the increment expression itself (i.e. `++index` / `index++` -- the `for`-loop does not use the result of these expressions; the result is thrown away).

Comment: @ozankurucu let index = 0 will execute then it goes into loop, not it will increment first

Comment: @BenCotrell Actually, for loop using the result of ++index/index++ because of both log are 0,1,2,3,4. Do you know why the first result of ++index is thrown away?

Answer (score 0):

First loop use post, and second loop use pre increment. The desc like this
++index (pre-increment) means "increment the variable; the value of the expression is the final value"
Index++ (post-increment) means "remember the original value, then increment the variable; the value of the expression is the original value"

Or u can follow this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469896/17123841