# Increment/decrement operator with this keyword in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, operators

I have a component with a property count=0;. When inside the ts code i  write

```
console.log(this.count--);
```

it prints 0. What is wrong?

Comment: Just check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Comment: It's a post increment, it will be incremented after being evaluated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [++someVariable vs. someVariable++ in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript)

Comment: And what's wrong? Function is called with old value ` 0`, then value is decremented. Javascript basics. Nothing to do with angular and typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to execute has nothing to do with Angular in particular, it is just plain javascript. By adding the -- operator to the end of the expression, you use the value first, and then update it. `console.log(this.count--);` is therefore equivalent to: `console.log(this.count); this.count = this.count - 1;` I believe that you can achieve your expected result by moving the operator to the beginning: `console.log(--this.count);` which would evaluate to: `this.count = this.count - 1; console.log(this.count);`