# JavaScript code working only in Debugger CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have the following line of code to refresh the parent form OnClose of Child form:

```
var popup = window.open(url, 'New Note', 'width=700,height=700');
 popup.focus();
```

**Problem at below line**

```
 popup.onbeforeunload = RefreshGrid;
```

**If I attach a breakpoint at above line using Developer Tools in IE-11 then alert is displayed and SomeWork is done: If I remove break-point then alert is not displayed and SomWork in not done.**

```
function RefreshGrid() {    
alert("refresh grid");
SomeWork();
}
```

I have tried alot of different methods but all have the same problem, runs with Break-point and does not run without break-point.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski leave the alert, SomeWork is also not runing. 
That's the real problem

Comment: I have a SubGrid, that i want to refresh, it contains asynchronous Ajax call.
How can i refresh ??

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Event loop halts after the event. I cannot understand it. Please explain it to me. thanks

Comment: If you don't own (same origin) the content of the popup, as your comment below might suggest, try "[detect closing popup loaded with another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694567/javascript-detect-closing-popup-loaded-with-another-domain)."

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind to onbeforeunload inside the pop up window. from the onbeforeunload event handler go to opener.RefreshGrid or opener.SomeWork

EDIT:
This might be a cross domain issue. Consider putting the external URL in an IFRAME inside a controllable popup window i.e. in the same domain of your CRM app.

If you’re browsing with IE you might also consider changing zone security setting for this specific website.

Comment: I do not have control over the Page in pop up window