# Chrome app: open external URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Well I say Chrome app but it's not exactly a Chrome app. It's just a HTML5 page that runs on Chrome.

So I have an `app.js` that defines the control flow of how the app would behave. Somewhere in the control flow, I'd like to open an external URL and let user play with that page. Afterwards, the control should go back to `app.js` and something else would happen.

But of course when Chrome load another page, all control is lost and there will be no `app.js` anymore. The external is from third party and thus cannot be modified.

How does one achieve this?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17744260/456135) may help

Comment: Open the page in a new window?

Comment: @Chris all these has to happen without user interaction. Suppose I have no control over the 3rd party page at all

Comment: Yes, you can open a page in a new window without user interaction. When the user closes it they will be returned to your app.