# How to use SyntaxHighlighter on a sharepoint 2013 blog (Office365)?

Tags: javascript, events, sharepoint-2013, syntax-highlighting, office365

I'm trying to allow code highlighting using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/about.html) on a sharepoint 2013 blog site (office365 portal).

Here is the code I have put in the head of the masterpage (js and css ressources are loaded before) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sh(){
        SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
    };

    // executed when SP load completes
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("sh");
</script>
```

The _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames should provide a mechanism to run functions after the *load* page event, but it seems it's never executed.
Running my sh function from the developper tool (console) is working as expected.

Does anybody have a clue, am I using the right event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+Vadim Gremyachev's answer is valid with IE, but doesnt work with chrome, here is the workaround I've used (inspirated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2956980/381149 ):

```
function sh(){
    SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
};

function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions) {
    var x = 0;
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {

       callback();

       if (++x === repetitions) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalID);
       }
    }, delay);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if( $('.syntaxhighlighter').length == 0 ){
        setIntervalX(function() { sh() }, 1000,5);
}

$("a").on("click",function () {
if( $('.syntaxhighlighter').length == 0 ){
    setIntervalX(function() {
      sh()
    }, 1000,5);
}
return true;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` array  declared in `init.js` (it is a part of SharePoint JavaScript Library)

According to `init.js`:

```
AttachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", _spBodyOnLoadWrapper, document);
window.onload = _spBodyOnLoadWrapper;
```

where

```
function _spBodyOnLoadWrapper() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ProcessDefaultOnLoad, "core.js");
    //the remaining code is omitted for clarity..
}


function ProcessDefaultOnLoad() {
    ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames(_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames);
    //the remaining code is omitted for clarity..
}
function ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames(onLoadFunctionNames) {
    if (onLoadFunctionNames != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < onLoadFunctionNames.length; i++) {
            var expr = "if(typeof(" + onLoadFunctionNames[i] + ")=='function'){" + onLoadFunctionNames[i] + "();}";

            eval(expr);
        }
        onLoadFunctionNames = [];
    }
}
```

To summarize, the specified approach is a **proper** mechanism to run functions after the load page event.

In fact it works for me just fine (see the picture below)

Make sure `init.js` library is loaded before `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` is initialized.

Alternatively you could try the following approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sh(){
        SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
    };

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(sh, "core.js");
</script>
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: I can't find where the init.js is loaded but your alternate approach works fine thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a 100% working answer, i will post my workaround as an answer