# JavaScript: setTimeout not updating value inside loop

Tags: javascript, css, closures, settimeout, iife

*I'm aware of closures, IIFE. 

I've read the other answers (they all point to using IIFE).

So why is this not working?*

- my image should gradually fade-in (in 2s)
- it seems like it's only rendering once (with final value)

```js
var imgFade = document.getElementById('img-fade');
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  (function(step) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      imgFade.style.opacity = (step/100);
    }, 20);
  })(i);
}
```

here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/Lh10phuv/1/

**EDIT:** for future readers
consider all answers transitioning from `i = 1; to 1 <= 100, i++`
 so it won't stop rendering at 99%

Comment: Well, you're setting a whole bunch of timeouts practically at once to be executed 20ms later; they're all going to fire extremely rapidly one after the other. You'll have to spread out the timing a bit for it to be *gradual*.

Comment: @deceze that's not the issue, or a simple extra 0 on the setTimeout would've fixed it.

Comment: @warkentien2 I think it is the issue, because there's literally nanoseconds between the first `setTimeout` being made and the last one. So all you will see is the last one. `setInterval` is probably what you need.

Comment: @deceze seems to be right. The settimeout calls dont get called 20ms apart, they all get called at once in ~20ms

Comment: @deceze well I did say it seems to all be rendering at once. Still don't understand why. (I did bump up the interval to 1000 each. only one render "blink" already 100% opacity) // So you're solution is to create a setInterval at 20ms each, run it 100 times then pause it? How will it update the opacity value? I'm gonna try this.

Comment: Think about it: this loop is going to run in a fraction of a second, setting 100 callbacks to execute ~20ms later. Each callback is also just going to take a fraction of a second, after which the next callback runs. So your execution is 0% opacity, loop, ... 20ms nothing ... 1,2,3,4...100% opacity within a fraction of a second. Visually that change will appear to be instantaneous. You either want to set the timeout as `20 * i` to successively delay each callback more and more, or you need to trigger the next callback 20ms after the previous one has finished.

Comment: @deceze now that I know the answer, you're correct. For all calls must happen after one another. It just sounded like that interval was 20ms each, not 20ms before, and a practical at once for all the callbacks. But thanks for helping out! And you're correct to state that tecnically they are not running at the same time (just virtually)

Answer (score 4):

A quick but dirty way is multiplying the `20` by `step`. You create all the timeouts at once, so the ones that are supposed to be executed later have higher delay:

```
var imgFade = document.getElementById('img-fade');
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  (function(step) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      imgFade.style.opacity = (step/100);
    }, step * 20);
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Traditionally, people do [`setInterval` like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956966/javascript-telling-setinterval-to-only-fire-x-amount-of-times), but I like this much better.

Comment: so I was creating all the setTimeouts at once! It took me a while to believe it. I thought it worked as a system('pause'); Thanks! And that not a dirty trick at all. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this spams the execution queue with a hundred callbacks at once. While probably not a big problem in practice, it'd be more efficient to schedule the next callback at the end of the previous one. It would also allow you to cancel the fade-in at any time, which gets a bit hard to do when the entire thing is already scheduled to execute with no real way to cancel a hundred callbacks.

Comment: @deceze what do you mean callbacks? `setTimeout` has no callback. And, not sure if I'm understanding it right, but still sounds like a loop. Could you send me a function example?

Comment: @warkentien2 Callback is any piece of code that you pass to a function to be executed when the function ends or after some time. `setTimeout` is a typical example of function with a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Heres another solution, applying the fade in one after another:

```
var fade = function(step){
  imgFade.style.opacity = (step/100);
  if(step < 100){
    setTimeout(function(){ fade(++step); }, 20);
  }
};

fade(0);
```

Comment: nice recursion! Now that I get the problem, I can think of a few solutions myself. But I'm giving due credit.

Comment: I think a nicer version of this would use `--step` and `if(step > 0)`. That way you can change the number of iterations by changing the initial parameter.

Comment: Sweet, glad you understand how its working! @4castle yes thats an improvement for sure