# call php function every 5 sec

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, timer

hi i wanna ask how can i call php function on every 5 sec
i tried with this:
This is my php

```
function php_func() {
    $link = mysql_connect("localhos", "SD_users", "users123");
    mysql_select_db("crazyde_SD_users", $link);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `user` WHERE user1 = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        if($row['user2']!="none") {
            $new="ok";
        }
    }
    echo $new;
}
```

Below is **my Js CODE :**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var result = "php_func();";
if(result =="ok") {
    alert(result);
} else
    alert("no"); 
}, 5000);
```

but it call the function only one time when i load the file
i think i can do it with Ajax but i don't know how

Comment: Please format your code properly by indenting it by four spaces.

Comment: This is not my answer but follow this stackoverflow answer for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956966/javascript-telling-setinterval-to-only-fire-x-amount-of-times

Comment: Once your page is loaded, the result you're going to get will be the same as the first time you loaded the page. You need ajax to communicate to the server.

Comment: yeah I know but can't work with ajax

Comment: Whats the problem with ajax? Also you can not call a php function like the way you did in the above question.

Comment: Ajax is only the best option available.