# Call app component ngOnInit() second time on click of a link

Tags: angular

I am restructuring an angular project where I found below functionality.

In app.component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
this.portfolioID = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('portfolioID'));
console.log(this.portfolioID);
this.sharedService.getPortfilioID().subscribe(portfolioID => {
  if (portfolioID && portfolioID !== 0) {
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.displayText === 'Business Licenses' && item.items.length > 0) {
        item.items.forEach(childItem => {
          childItem.url = childItem.defaultUrl;
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
}
```

They are getting some Id from localstorage which was set by clicking on a link in another component.

Another.component.html

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem *ngIf="column.isActionable && titleName == 'Customer Search'">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" *ngIf="column.attributeName == 'portfolioName'"
      (click)="viewPortfolioDetails(dataItem.portfolioID)">{{dataItem.portfolioName}}</a>
  </ng-template>
```

Another.component.ts

```
viewPortfolioDetails(portfolioID: number) {
sessionStorage.setItem('portfolioID', portfolioID.toString());
this.sharedService.setPortfolioID(portfolioID);
}
```

So, as it was set on click, initially when page loads first time before click, I am not able to get the ID and the subsequent functionality is not working. So, my question is can I call the onInit() method of the app.component again? Or is there any better approach to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this other component in the app component template?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following link [Javascript - telling setInterval to only fire x amount of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956966/javascript-telling-setinterval-to-only-fire-x-amount-of-times)

Here You can write contents of your `oninit()` using  `setintervalX()`

This way you can call contents of oninit multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call the `ngOnInit()` twice. The variable `childItem.url` will be set in app component as long the `portfolioID`s are pushed correctly to the observable in the shared service. You could try the following in the service

Shared service

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private portfolioIdSource = new Subject<number>();
  private portfolioId$ = this.portfolioIdSource.asObservable();

  public setPortfolioID(portfolioID: number) {
    this.portfolioIdSource.next(portfolioID);
  }

  public getPortfilioID(): Observable<number> {
    return this.portfolioId$;
  }
}
```

And also make sure the value obtained from session storage is used at the beginning of the app life-cycle.

App component

```js
subscription: any;

ngOnInit() {
  const portfolioID = sessionStorage.getItem('portfolioID');    // <-- will be called only once at the beginning of app life-cycle
  if (portfolioID !== null && Number(portfolioID) !== 0) {
    this.setUrl();
  }

  this.subscription = this.sharedService.getPortfilioID().subscribe(    // <-- will be triggered everytime new portfolioID is pushed
    portfolioID => {
      if (portfolioID && portfolioID !== 0) {           // <-- will not be called at app beginning because no value in observable 
        this.setUrl();
      }
    }
  );
}

setUrl() {
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.displayText === 'Business Licenses' && item.items.length > 0) {
      item.items.forEach(childItem => {
        childItem.url = childItem.defaultUrl;
      });
    }
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: in setUrl() method, items is not accessible right? forEach is not working with this approach.

Comment: In the code you've shown in the question, `this.items` is a member variable and it should be available everywhere in the component.