# how to run click event 10 times

Tags: javascript, html

**My Code**

```
window.onload = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0]!="undefined"){
        document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].click();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" >Auto click</button>
```

i want to click `button` as `class="btn-primary"` only 10 time. but i won't find the code for it. my code repeats clicking every 1s.

Now my question is, how can i click the `button` only 10 times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - telling setInterval to only fire x amount of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956966/javascript-telling-setinterval-to-only-fire-x-amount-of-times)

Comment: The title is currently telling that the event repeats 10 times which is not the case in your question. You can change it to something like “how to run click event 10 times?”

Comment: Where do you attempt to limit the number of clicks to 10?

Comment: in `button`  `class="btn-primary"`

Comment: @AbuNaaimMd.MontasirRahman What about that class? How does its presence limit the amount of clicks to 10?

Comment: @SebastianSimon i don't understand what you asked. My question was, how can i click a button only 10 times and then stop clicking the button.  but in my code its repeated clicking every 1sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `setInterval` function, that function will trigger each time on the specified interval, you have to use `clearInterval` once the limit is reached.

```js
function clickme() {
  console.log('You clicked me');
}
let intervalFunction;
let count = 0;
window.onload = function () {
  intervalFunction = setInterval(function () {
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0] != "undefined") {
      document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].click();
      count++;
      if (count === 10) {
        console.log("Now you have clicked me 10 times!! let me take a break")
        clearInterval(intervalFunction)
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary" onclick="clickme()">Click me</button>
```

If you dont need to have the interval between each click, you can direcly click it with a loop.

**Example**

```js
function clickme() {
  console.log('You clicked me');
}
let intervalFunction;
let count = 0;
window.onload = function () {
  while(count < 10) {
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0] != "undefined") {
      document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].click();
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary" onclick="clickme()">Click me</button>
```